# Is it possible to navigate to msbuild errors in VS 2017 that are collected in an arbitrary text file, rather than the error list pane?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have a file with msbuild errors which I want to open in VS 2017 (the relevant solution is already open) and be able to navigate the errors and warnings as if they are open in the Error List pane.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Found it. One can make an External Tool that just outputs the contents of the given file. It is important to use the Output pane for the output. So, the procedure to navigate to errors would be:

1. Open the errors file as a regular file in VS
2. Run the aforementioned External Tool - the file would be output in the output pane.
3. That's it - one click the lines in the output pane to navigate.